# javascript get a total for a table column NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a NaN error. the code was copied from a fiddle which works perfectly.   Here is the code.

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="payment_id[]" id="payment_id_" value="6" class="box" checked="checked" /></td>                
            <td>2015-08-26 20:43:50 UTC</td>
            <td>1000002043</td>
            <td class = "amount">25.0</td>
            <td>CHK</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href="/payments/6">Show</a></td>
            <td><a href="/payments/6/edit">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/payments/6">Destroy</a></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
      <td>Total</td><td><div id="total"></div></td>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$(function() {
$('.box').change(function(){

   var total = 0;
   $('.box:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseFloat($(this).parent().next('td').find('.amount').text());
   });       
   $('#total').text(total);
});
});
```

I am getting a NaN in the total element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break down your jQuery chain:

```
$(this) // ,box
    .parent() // The <td>
    .next('td') // The next <td> in the sequence
    .find('.amount') // Tries to find an element with class `amount` inside the <td>
    .text() // Empty, because the previous element doesn't exist
```

What you'll need to do is append the `.amount` onto your selector and use `nextAll` instead, like so:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll("td.amount").text()
```

If you had multiple `amount` classes, you'd need to make sure you only picked the first one like so:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll("td.amount:first").text()
```

Example:

```js
$('.box').change(function(){

   var total = 0;
   $('.box:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseFloat($(this).parent().nextAll('td.amount').text());
   });       
   $('#total').text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="payment_id[]" id="payment_id_" value="6" class="box" checked="checked" /></td>                
            <td>2015-08-26 20:43:50 UTC</td>
            <td>1000002043</td>
            <td class = "amount">25.0</td>
            <td>CHK</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href="/payments/6">Show</a></td>
            <td><a href="/payments/6/edit">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/payments/6">Destroy</a></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the amount is entered once per row I jumped back to row and found the td.amount in the row.

```
(function($) {
    $('.box').change(function(){
       var total = 0;
       $('.box:checked').each(function(){
            total += parseFloat($('td.amount', $(this).closest('tr')).text());
       });       
       $('#total').text(total);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a referencing error. Use:

```
$(function() {
$('.box').change(function(){

   var total = 0;
   $('.box:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('td.amount').text());
   });       
   $('#total').text(total);
});
});
```